# Okio native/multiplatform default paths

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, okio

How do one access the common default paths using okio?

The paths I'm specifically interested in are:

- Application directory (location of the executable(s) that are being run)
- Working directory (where the app is run from, seems that it's relative to the `FileSystem`?)
- Temporary directory

For the temporary directory I found `FileSystem.SYSTEM_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY`, is this the correct/best way?

Can I, as I suspect get working directory by assuming that it's local to the `FileSystem`, if so, is this reliable, or just how it happens to be right now?

What about the application directory?

I've seen that a users home directory isn't implemented due to the ambiguity of it, and issues with platforms such as Android where the notion of a home directory is a bit weird. And for that reason I suspect there's no direct helpers/variables in okio, and that I need to work around the system directly, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Application directory (location of the executable(s) that are being run)

No clue. What would you use with `java.nio`?

> Working directory (where the app is run from, seems that it's relative to the FileSystem?)

I think you could work with `".".toPath()`, does it not work?

> Temporary directory

As you said, `FileSystem.SYSTEM_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: In java.nio I'd probably do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/320595/1441857 I know the korio library has a solution, but I'm a bit uncertain how they got it working. But if we can get a solution, that'd be nice so the answer can be complete :)

Comment: Actually I think this is how it's done in korio: https://github.com/korlibs/korge/blob/fa3a118cdcc05bcb52303afe67e93e396fabe279/korio/src/linuxMain/kotlin/com/soywiz/korio/file/std/StandardBasePathsJs.kt

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at [https://github.com/korlibs/korge](https://github.com/korlibs/korge/blob/fa3a118cdcc05bcb52303afe67e93e396fabe279/korio/src/linuxMain/kotlin/com/soywiz/korio/file/std/StandardBasePathsJs.kt) (recommendation of @oldergod above)

To determin the current working directory (aka application directory)
I came up with these functions, that work on native via POSIX and jvm via `File(".")`

commonMain:

```kotlin
import okio.Path

expect fun cwd(): Path
```

jvmMain:

```kotlin
import okio.Path
import okio.Path.Companion.toPath
import java.io.File

// one of:
// actual fun cwd(): Path = File(File(".").absolutePath).canonicalPath.toPath()
actual fun cwd(): Path = File(".").absolutePath.toPath(normalize = true)
```

nativeMain:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import okio.FileSystem
import okio.Path
import okio.Path.Companion.toPath
import platform.posix.PATH_MAX
import platform.posix.getcwd

actual fun cwd(): Path = memScoped {
    val temp = allocArray<ByteVar>(PATH_MAX + 1)
    getcwd(temp, PATH_MAX.convert())
    temp.toKString()
}.toPath(normalize = true)
```

maybe usefull for somebody coming across this thread.